# Typing a polymorphic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Here is what I am trying to type:

```js
type CallbackMap = {
  n: (value: number) => void;
  s: (value: string) => void;
};

type MyFunction = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(
  callbacks: CallbackMap[K][]
) => CallbackMap[K];

const myFunction: MyFunction = (callbacks) => (value) => {
  //                                           ^^^^^ (1)
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    callback(value);
    //       ^^^^^ (2)
  }
};

myFunction([(value: number) => {}])(1);
//                                  ^ (3)
myFunction([(value: string) => {}])("one");
//                                  ^^^^^ (4)
```

[Link to the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYFk5igXigG8AoKKAOwC4oAKAN0QFcIaKmBbZCAJwEoCAPij0A9gEsAJgG4yUAM40GzVguA9xFAOYD8wsVNkBfWSVCQoWEADEmFNMHGiKBKAB4A0lAgAPYBApJeSgMCBBRADNYRBR0bFxBWjk0GNRMRWikNPiwAG0PAF1cgpJdYXgsuJw8wtM0Z3lgKA4bOwcnaktW+0dnV1oUyvSyukYEFhHScgjRHjp6ikaoQdjMKEjl1Lj5ASnyTaGMZXGIPllyIxITEhIW2x6O2lzjljZObn4hYiMCvloARjOt267WcTxeqkaGm0kx+fwARM4IPCgUA)

So `myFunction` takes an array of callbacks as a parameter and returns a function having the same signature than the callbacks in the array passed to `myFunction`. Calling the function returned by `myFunction` would then call every callback in the array of callbacks passing them the argument `value` given to the function.

There are 4 errors with this code:

```
(1) Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
(2) Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
(3) Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
(4) Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

I can get rid of errors `(1)`, `(3)`, and `(4)`, by refactoring the type of the return value of `myFunction`:

```js
type MyFunction = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(
  callbacks: CallbackMap[K][]
) => (value: Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]) => void;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (callbacks) => (value) => {
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    callback(value);
    //       ^^^^^ (5)
  }
};
```

[Link to the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYFk5igXigG8AoKKAOwC4oAKAN0QFcIaKmBbZCAJwEoCAPij0A9gEsAJgG4yUAM40GzVguA9xFAOYD8wsVNkBfWSVCQoWEADEmFNMHGiKBKAB4A0lAgAPYBApJeSgMCBBRADNYRBR0bFxBWjk0GNRMRWikNPiwAG0PAF1cgpJdYWUEFhoABTgeOA4Ifx55N3gsuJw8wsFcgAYCspEJGRISNGd5YCgOGzsHJ2pLOftHZ1daFI70oYqWIdJyCNEeOgmKKagt2MwoSKvUuPkBQ-IH7Yw9iD5ZciMSExjWa2VaLWi5L5sTjcfhCYhGQa0ACMPxIwPmawo4Mhag02gOCL4tAARM4IMTUUA)

Now the only error left is:

```
(5) Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

With a bit of refactoring the types can be rewritten like this:

```js
type Callback<V> = (value: V) => void;

type CallbackMap = {
  n: Callback<number>;
  s: Callback<string>;
};

type MyFunction = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(
  callbacks: CallbackMap[K][]
) => Callback<Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]>;
```

[Link to the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYB4BqA+KAXigAoA3RAVwgC4ocBKIgsgewEsATAbgChfQkWIhToMAWThgiUAN68oUAHZ14SVJixLKAW2QQATnj6KAzqpEbsp4AfZKA5sd4BfPgPDRxIAGKUlaMDsrEoyWADSUBAAHsAQSpymUBgQIKwAZsLqYpJgeCQKUGiWYuZZopi5ANrhALpVtbxMhARqFdgACnAGcDoQcQamWG1W1XV4VQAMtc68aCE2UDq+-oHBKlDefgFBITIkxdmYps0E5FQQp3KF6awGpPNKi4ftUBlFJcdM8oqKL1bnBDUBgmKAuVzuZbbNYhEhVQHUOjaPSGK6yFy1BgkACMIN4UNWuyUcIRtCgNjsjjRGKxACIQhBaXigA)

Refactoring the type of the `callbacks` parameter of `myFunction` the same way would only move the issue to the function calls:

```js
type MyFunction = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(
  callbacks: Callback<Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]>[]
) => Callback<Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]>;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (callbacks) => (value) => {
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    callback(value);
  }
};

myFunction([(value: number) => {}])(1);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (6)
myFunction([(value: string) => {}])("one");
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (7)
```

[Link to the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYB4BqA+KAXigAoA3RAVwgC4ocBKIgsgewEsATAbgChfQkWIhToMAWThgiUAN68oUAHZ14SVJixLKAW2QQATnj6KAzqpEbsp4AfZKA5sd4BfPgPDRxIAGKUlaMDsrEoyWADSUBAAHsAQSpymUBgQIKwAZsLqYpJgeCQKUGiWYuZZopoACnAGcDoQcQamWGoVElIA2uEAungdAAy9Hd28TIQErVZY1bX1jc2TOZ09fYPOvGghNlA6vv6BwSpQ3n4BQSEyJMXZmKZjBORUEPdyhemsBqSbStvXbVAZIolW5MeSKRR-KyPBDUBgmKAuVzuXanA4hEgdaHUOjaPSGF6yFzdBgkACMcN4KP25yUGKxtCgNjsjgJRJJACIQhB2RSgA)

Errors on the function calls:

```
(6) Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'Callback<string | number>'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
(7) Type '(value: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'Callback<string | number>'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Is there a way to type `myFunction` without TypeScript complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript code provided is almost correct, but the type definition of MyFunction is incorrectly defined. It tries to infer the type of the generic K from the callbacks parameter, but it's not directly possible to infer the type of K like this, which is the cause of the error.

```js
type Callback<V> = (value: V) => void;

type CallbackMap = {
  n: Callback<number>;
  s: Callback<string>;
};

type MyFunction = <K extends keyof CallbackMap>(
  callbacks: Callback<Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]>[]
) => Callback<Parameters<CallbackMap[K]>[0]>;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (callbacks) => (value) => {
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    callback(value);
  }
};

myFunction<"n">([(value: number) => {}])(1);
myFunction<"s">([(value: string) => {}])("one");
```

Edit: Used Type inference during function call as opposed to extra argument

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, you actually made me realize what I was missing: inferring the type of K. There is actually a way to pass it to `myFunction` without having to add an extra parameter, you would just need to specify it like this: `myFunction<"n">(...)`. I still accepted your answer, it’s up to you if you want to edit it or not.

Comment: That's right! I have edited the answer to reflect this. Glad it helped.